# Help resolving apparent ambiguity: P(A|B,C) = P(A|(B,C)) or P((A|B), C)?

Tags: conditional-probability, notation

Per title, it always confuses me than not, specially when more random variables are used. There is more than one way to get confused imho:

1. (As in title) P(A|B,C) = P(A|(B,C)) or P((A|B), C)?
2. P(A,B|C) = P((A,B)|C) or P(A,(B|C))?

Is it understood from context? Or is there a more rigorous way to prioritize how to unpack the notation in these cases?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Why do you think adding parentheses to the first expression to get the second expression is meaningful?  2.  The vertical bar $|$ means, roughly, "given the values of"; what is unclear about $P(A|B,C)$ that you would think it needs improved notation?  3. Given this meaning of $|$, $P((A|B),C)$ clearly doesn't mean the same thing as $P(A|B,C)$.

Comment: Hmm, apparently @jbowman you do not share my confusion. Well, let me respond to your questions. 1. b/c the 2 events are different, like imagine in the context of several random vars. Xn | X1,...,Xn-1 makes sense but the notation alone does not differentiate between the former and Xn|X1 , X2,...,Xn-1.    2. and 3. Well, if you're saying (A|B),C can only be referred to by using parentheses, sure, I'll take that.

Answer (score 4):

In probability formulas, *commas* usually mean *intersection* and so the commonly used $P(A\mid B,C)$ is "shorthand" for $P(A\mid B\cap C)$, or, for true nitpickers, $P(A\mid (B\cap C))$ to prevent these who greatly enjoy parsing $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ as $P((A\mid B) \cap C)$  from doing so.

**There is no such thing as an event $A\mid B$ or $(A\mid B)$,** and so $P((A\mid B) \cap C)$ is meaningless. What's on *both* sides of the $\mid$ must be an event, no ifs, ands, or buts about it, In OP's $P((A\mid B) \cap C)$, the $A\mid B$ or $(A\mid B)$ is *not* an event and so it is meaningless to compute its intersection with event $C$.  When one writes $P(A\mid B)$, what is meant is the *conditional probability* of the event $A$ -- just the event $A$, no more, no less -- *conditioned* on the event $B$ having occurred.  If the event on the right side of $\mid$ has more complicated formula, say $B\cap C$ or $B,C$ (which, as mentioned before, means $B\cap C$), then $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ is the *conditional probability* of the event $A$ -- just the event $A$, no more, no less -- *conditioned* on the event $B\cap C$ having occurred.  One does not move the $\mid$ into the middle of the event description on the right.  Similarly, $P(A\cap B \mid C)$ is the conditional probability of the event $A\cap B$ conditioned on the event $C$ having occurred; it is *not* the probability of the intersection of events $A$ and $B\mid C$ -- $B\mid C$ is *not* an event.

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciated. My confusion of A|B as an event came from thinking of it as A∩B as a subset of B (for the sake of computation), but your response clarified this issue completely.

Comment: +1 -- but I think the language is a little confusing.  What is on "both sides" of $|$ in "$\Pr((A\mid B)\cap C)$" are the events $A$ and $B,$ which is not a problem.  The issue with $(A\mid B)\cap C)$ is that $A\mid B$ is not a set at all, making it meaningless to intersect it with $C.$

Comment: @whuber I edited my answer.